# File can be found using os.listdir(), but cannot be read

Tags: python, file-io

I'm making a program that combines a number of images into a PDF, and it worked so far. When I tried another example, the program broke.

I looked in with the debugger, and found out that the file cannot be read by Python, since it cannot find the file. I tried using os.listdir() to find all files in the directory, and the image did show up here. When I read the file using python's normal read function, it could not find the file. This is especially annoying since the module I'm using for making the PDF files, img2pdf, uses this function. I therefore cannot change it to make it work. It also uses open(filename, 'rb'), so I cannot change that either.

```py
#Running os.listdir() returns the list, including the following image
print(os.listdir())
#Gives a FileNotFoundError
with open('sbr_color_v03_052_01.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output of os.listdir()

```
['sbr_color_v03_037.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_038.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_039.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_040.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_041.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_042.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_043.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_044.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_045.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_046.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_047.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_048.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_049.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_050.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_051.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_052_01.jpg',
 'sbr_color_v03_052_02.jpg']
```

I copy pasted the second-to-last filename into the open() function shown above, so it should be the same filename
Output of open() function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-20-06e5363219b6>", line 1, in <module>
    with open('sbr_color_v03_052_01.jpg', 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sbr_color_v03_052_01.jpg'
```

Comment: Try providing the absolute file path.

Comment: What does `os.getcwd()` return before each call? (`listdir` and `open`)